# Plotting color in multi-timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I have problem with plotting color in multi-timeframe.  The color of trailing stop didn't change after trailing line has changed in different timeframe.

[image: 1]

```
atrTimeframe = input.timeframe(title="ATR Timeframe", defval="60")
atrPeriod = input.int(10, "ATR Period")
atrMultiplier = input.float(3, "ATR Multiplier", step=.1)

ATR = ta.atr(atrPeriod)
Stop = atrMultiplier*ATR

atrStop() =>
    var atrTrailingstop = 0.0
    atrTrailingstop := if close>atrTrailingstop[1] and close[1]>atrTrailingstop[1]
        math.max(atrTrailingstop[1], close-Stop)
    else if close<atrTrailingstop[1] and close[1]<atrTrailingstop[1]
        math.min(atrTrailingstop[1], close+Stop)
    else if close>atrTrailingstop[1]
        close-Stop 
    else 
        close+Stop

atrTrailingstop = atrStop()
var Position = 0.0
Position := if close[1]<atrTrailingstop[1] and close>atrTrailingstop[1]
    1
else if close[1]>atrTrailingstop[1] and close<atrTrailingstop[1]
    -1
else
    Position[1]

atrSecure = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, atrTimeframe, atrStop(), gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)

PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
plot(atrSecure, color=PlotColor, linewidth=input(1, "Line Width", group=atrGroup), title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `atrStop()` in your `security()` function but your color is based on the value of `Position` as seen below.

```
PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
```

`Position` still refers to your chart's timeframe.

In order to fix it, you can also pass `PlotColor` to your `security()` call together with `atrStop()`.

```
PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue

[atrSecure, plotColorMtf] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, atrTimeframe, [atrStop(), PlotColor], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)

plot(atrSecure, color=plotColorMtf, linewidth=input(1, "Line Width", group=atrGroup), title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```